# How do i redirect or hide the output of the system parameters when running a stopservice command remotely in powershell

Tags: powershell

So i am using WMI objects to remotely restart a service, which works, but the output puts a load of parameters into the window, which is useful for me for debugging, but not for the end user.

I send the following

```
 Try {
       Write-host "Connecting to remote computer"
     $service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $till -Credential $cred -Filter "Name='$servname'"
       Write-host "Stopping service"
       $service.stopservice()
       Write-host "Waiting for service to stop"
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
       Write-host "Starting service"
       $service.startservice()
}
Catch {
        Write-host "There was an error processing your request" -fore RED;
}
```

The output i get is

```
Connecting to remote computer
Stopping service


__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   : 

Waiting for service to stop
Starting service
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :
```

I find the ReturnValue to be useful for this script and nothing else.

How can I hide this output and at the same time, use the ReturnValue so i can pipe it to a Switch statement

Comment: have you tried to assign it to a $Var? if you want to toss all of the output, the usual ways to dump unwanted output are ... [1] `[void]$Thing.CallThatProducesOutput()` [2] `$null = $Thing.CallThatProducesOutput()` [3] `$Thing.CallThatProducesOutput() | Out-Null`

Comment: piping it to null works, i can hide it from the end user, but i would like to be able to grab some of the value namely the "ReturnValue" which gives the result of the command including error states etc and use that for followup, as a second restart might be required or a longer wait etc.

Comment: so, what happens when you assign it to a $Var? [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to assign the call to a $Var. [*grin*] that will give you access to the `.ReturnValue` property. here's a demo ...

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'Spooler'"
$Service.State
''
$StopResponse = $Service.StopService()
$StopResponse.ReturnValue
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'Spooler'").State
''
$StartResponse = $Service.StartService()
$StartResponse.ReturnValue
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'Spooler'").State
```

output ...

```
Running

0
Stopped

0
Running
```

Comment: Excellent, this solves the problem, and i can pass the new variable through to a switch to display a friendly version of the return value.

Comment: @DavidMcGowan - kool! glad to know you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]